# Open Script with ArcMap hyperlink on a new window

Tags: arcmap, python-script-tool, hyperlink

I am using a hyperlink to open my script,

```
import def_measure
def OpenLink ([weg_name] , [path], [Color_Frame]  ):
  bag_path = [path] 
  weg_id = [weg_name]  
  color_id = [Color_Frame]
  def_measure.frame_match(bag_path,weg_id,color_id)
  return
```

this is opening .bag file from realsense camera frame with matplotlib

so, sometimes the realsense pipeline it self freeze, still waiting for update.

because of this reason, my ArcMap will also freeze because it can't end the script.

I would like to know if there is a method that I can open one extra python window and run my script with the input value from my attribute, so ArcMap won't crash while the script it fails

I've been looking into subprocess but can't get python run in cmd without admin